# "Certificate verify failed" while using http://rubygems.org instead of https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, certificate, windows-10

I used to get a certificate verification error when I used the https:/rubygems.org.

A workaround was suggested: remove the "s" (so I end up using http instead of https). It worked for some time but today after starting a new rails application  `rails new 'filename'` I got the same certificate validation error:

> Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
>   server certificate B: certificate verify failed
>   (https://rubygems.org/gems/mime-types-data-3.2016.0521.gem)
>   An error occurred while installing mime-types-data (3.2016.0521), and Bundler
>   cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0521'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

I typed `gem sources` only to find that https://rubygems.org doesn't even exist.

```
    $ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org
```

I go to the gemfile and I find

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `http://rubygems.org` redirects to `https://rubygems.org` so you are stuck with your original problem.

Comment: I just checked and the certificate chain that rubygems.org sends looks good, at least, as long as you trust the root certificate. The root certificate is `/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA` which is widely trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to update the certificate, http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Then look for default cert file

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE' that outputs "/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem"
```

And then renamed, that will use the new certificate you downloaded

```
mv /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem.old
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still seeing this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with ARMV7, ensure:

- `ca-certificates` is installed
- run `update-ca-certificates` at least once after updating OS packages

You may additionally need to install the GlobalSign certificate prior to running `update-ca-certificates`:

```
curl -sL -o /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/GlobalSignRootCA_R3.crt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA_R3.pem
```

This appeared to fix the issue for me.